# How to derive form of reflecting waves from black holes?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, coordinate-systems, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Consider a collapsing sphere that becomes a black hole. The interior schwartzchild lightcone coordinate $U$ can be written as $U$ = $\tau - r + R_{0}$ where $R_{0}$ is the radius of the sphere before collapse. The exterior light cone coordinate is

$u$ = $t-r^{*} + R^{*}_{0}$

where $R^{*}_{0} = \int{\frac{dR_{0}}{C}}$. $C$ is a function of $r$ and its precise form is irrelevant.

Before collapse at $\tau$ = 0, $r$ = $R_{0}$ and $u = U = 0$ at the surface of a sphere.
At $\tau > 0$, $r = R(\tau)$ (the sphere shrinks).

I’m trying to get a relation between $u$ and $U$ in order to find the form of the reflecting spherical modes in the gravitational collapse.

Page 255 of Birrell & Davies says

$$\frac{dU}{du} = \frac{(\dot{R} - 1)}{2\dot{R}}C(R) \tag{8.19}$$

Expanding $R(\tau)$ near horizon gives

$$R(\tau) = R_{h} + v(\tau_{h} - \tau) + …$$

$$v = -\dot{R}(\tau_h)$$ and $(R_{h},\tau_{h})$ is the location of the horizon.

Then [8.19] integrates to

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial C}{\partial r}u = -\ln(U + R_{h} - R_{0} - \tau_h)\tag{8.22}$$

I’m not sure what he means by integrating [8.19]. With respect to *what*? $u$? How does the expansion for $R(\tau)$ play into that?

In other words, how does one go from [8.19] to [8.22]?

Comment: This is just for the derivation of the extrinsic schwartzchild coordinate in terms of the intrinsic one for a collapsing sphere. Someone that has read the vhspter on quantum black holes would recognize it, no?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for asking, but are you giving all the informations listed in the book? For instance, what is $R_h$?

Comment: I edited it. It is the radius of the sphere at the horizon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to expand $C$ into a Taylor series. Then by writing $\dot{R(\tau)}$ in terms of its Taylor expansion. Then by rearranging and integrating with respect to $u$, the answer is derived.